# How to extract input from html form for axios post request

Tags: html, node.js, vue.js, axios

I am trying to send a post request to my API using axios. I have a html form where the user enters an email and a password. When the request is sent off, I can see in the chrome dev tools that the body of my request is empty, so I am not getting the form input. I would appreciate any advice on how I can extract this.

**The HTML form**

```
<modal name="modal-register" @opened="opened">
            <form @submit.prevent="doRegister">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email" class="block">Email</label>
                    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" class="border" ref="email">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="password" class="block">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" class="border">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button type="submit" @submit.prevent="doRegister">Register</button>
                </div>
            </form>
            <div class="form-group">
                <p>Already have an account? <a href="#">Login</a></p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <p v-if="success"> {{ success }}</p>
                <pre>{{ response }}</pre>
            </div>
        </modal>
```

**The Axios request**

```
doRegister() {
            axios({
                method: 'post',
                url: 'http://localhost:3001/wallets/signup',
                headers: {},
                data: {
                    email: this.email,
                    password: this.password
                }
            });
        }
```

When the values in the data block are hardcoded, the request works fine, so I am simply not extracting the form data. I am having trouble finding examples for doing this with javascript as most seem to use php for the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have to bind the inputs to your data.
So adding `v-model` to the inputs and bind them to your perferred data key. eg `this.email`/`this.password`

```
<modal name="modal-register" @opened="opened">
  <form @submit.prevent="doRegister">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="email" class="block">Email</label>
      <input v-model="email" type="email" id="email" name="email" class="border" ref="email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="password" class="block">Password</label>
      <input v-model="password" type="password" id="password" name="password" class="border">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <button type="submit" @submit.prevent="doRegister">Register</button>
    </div>
  </form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <p>Already have an account? <a href="#">Login</a></p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p v-if="success"> {{ success }}</p>
    <pre>{{ response }}</pre>
  </div>
</modal>
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue was resolved by using

```
email: document.getElementById('email').value,
password: document.getElementById('password').value
```

Comment: I would not advice you to do this. You are missing out on the whole point of vue.
With vue, you can bind keys to elements, making them reactive. Even tho this will fix it, its not a "vue way" to do this.

Comment: Oh. I am really new to vue and am not too familiar with binding keys. Would it essentially be done like v-model="email" in the form and then in the request v-bind:email="email" ?

Comment: Thats totally fine! :D You only do v-model on html elements. what this does is that it automatically assignes the element the value, at the same time it also updates the data key (in javascript) the input from the element. This way, you have a "live"/"reactive" html. You won't get this by using getElementById.value..

Comment: v-model in html `v-model="email"` will bind to the value in -> `data() {return { email: 'something@a.com' }}`. If you change the input in the html, the value in email in data will change, realtime.

Comment: ahh. Thats so cool. I chose vue for my frontend as I have built a restful node api and I read that vue was a great framework to connect the two. Thank you so much for the advice!

Comment: Yeah, that's the reason I'm in here helping people with vue; I find it so awesome and I want other people to do it too :D